# Create view match parent when don't know exactly content height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, match, parent

I have a layout like this

[image]

I want to create view like red line match parent item,but i don't know exactly content height. I try create view margin top equals a width of height imageview,but my content is set height wrap_content,so It's not work

This is my layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtContent"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/img" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/line"
    android:layout_width="5dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent" />
```

Comment: Elaborate your issue. Is it dynamic or static??

Comment: It is dinamic, my content can change

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/img"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:src="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/txtContent"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/img" />

<View
android:id="@+id/line"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="5dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/txtContent"
android:background="@color/colorAccent" />
```